# JOIN is not working as expected with gorm

Tags: go, join, go-gorm

I have some problems with getting the assigned role of the user. Here is the main Get Func :

```
func (repo *UserRepository) Get(userID int) (*models.User, error) {
    user := &models.User{}
    err := repo.dbClient.Debug().
        Joins("JOIN roles ON users.id = roles.id").Where("users.id = ?", userID).
        Select("users.*, roles.roles"). // Assuming you want to find a user by their ID
        Find(&user).Error

    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("failed to fetch user: %v\n", err)
        return nil, err
    }

    return user, nil
}
```

Here I try to return the user and his role.
Here are the structs:

```
type Roles struct {
    Id    int    `json:"id" gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Roles string `json:"roles"`
}
```

```
type User struct {
    Id        int     `json:"id" gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Name      string  `json:"name"`
    Password  string  `json:"pass"`
    ImagePath string  `json:"image"`
    Roles     []Roles ` gorm:"foreignKey:Id"`
}
```

The thing is that the both tables are not empty. But the returning result when i give a request is:

```
{
    "roles": [],
    "id": 3,
    "name": "fds",
    "password": "$2a$14$FqrXrgQJ/gAkHHj/Ac9Ci.nyANGZyU6dotBtKWMk2h9Ac/mnPkeEK",
    "image": ""
}
```

You can see that roles is empty.

I dont know how to solve this problem. Could you help me please?

Comment: Please note that your question has nothing to do with permissions: the tables in your example could just as well be orders and customers, inhabitants and cities and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of `Preload`:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "gorm.io/driver/sqlite"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

type User struct {
    Id        int     `json:"id" gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Name      string  `json:"name"`
    Password  string  `json:"pass"`
    ImagePath string  `json:"image"`
    Roles     []Roles `json:"roles" gorm:"foreignKey:user_id;references:id"`
}

func (*User) TableName() string {
    return "users"
}

type Roles struct {
    Id     int    `json:"id" gorm:"primaryKey"`
    UserId int    `json:"user_id"`
    Roles  string `json:"roles"`
}

func (*Roles) TableName() string {
    return "roles"
}

func main() {
    db, err := gorm.Open(sqlite.Open("test.db"), &gorm.Config{
        DisableForeignKeyConstraintWhenMigrating: true,
    })
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer os.Remove("test.db")
    if err := db.AutoMigrate(&User{}, &Roles{}); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    db.Create(&User{Id: 1, Name: "bob", Roles: []Roles{
        {Id: 1, Roles: "a,b,c"},
        {Id: 2, Roles: "a,b,c"},
    }})

    var out []*User
    db.Model(&User{}).Preload("Roles").Where("id=1").First(&out)
    b, _ := json.Marshal(&out)
    fmt.Println(string(b))
    // output:
    // [{"id":1,"name":"bob","pass":"","image":"","roles":[{"id":1,"user_id":1,"roles":"a,b,c"},{"id":2,"user_id":1,"roles":"a,b,c"}]}]

}
```

In your code, has some question:

If `Roles.Id` is the `User.Id`, then the `User.Roles` type should be `string` instead of `[]Roles`. Because the relation is `one to one`.

So in mine example code, I add `UserId` to `Roles` for the relation `one to many`.

More details see docs: [HasMany](https://gorm.io/docs/has_many.html) and [Preload](https://gorm.io/docs/preload.html)